# C++ Character Array, Placing Characters Backwards as an Ouput

Tags: c++, arrays, character

I need help with this assignment, its from a Computer Programming Course for new learners. It's a character array C++ code that is made broken, and I have to fix it. Except, I've been stuck on it for a very long time now and I'd like some assistance. If anyone could help me figure this out that'd be really great! Thank you!

```js
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string word[20];
  char inputword;
  int x;
  cout<<"Enter a word ";
  cin>>inputword;
  if(word[0] = 'a' || word[0] = 'e' || word[0] = 'i' ||
    word[0] = 'o' || word[0] = 'u')
      cout<<"Words that start with vowels are not easily translated to Pig Latin"<<endl;
  else
  {
    cout<<"In Pig Latin: ";
    while(word[x] != NULL)
    {
      cout<<word[x];
      ++x++;
    }
    cout<<word[0]<<"ay"<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `==` to test for equality in C++, `=` means assignment.

Comment: 1) what's wrong with it, 2) what have you done so far?

Comment: You need to make many changes.  When you are using `word[]` in `if()`, it is still undefined.  Besides, `word[]` is of type `string` while you are using it as a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins, I modified your code to work.  Hope this helps.

```
#include"stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
// #include<string>  // working w/char arrays, don't need std strings
#include <cstring> // include this file so we can use strlen (c-style strings)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char word[20];  // you're working with a char array (not string array)
  // char inputword; // you don't need a separate input data structure
  int x;
  cout<<"Enter a word ";
  cin>>word;  // input directly into the word array

  // use == to compare for equality, using = is assigning to word[0]
  if(word[0] == 'a' || word[0] == 'e' || word[0] == 'i' ||
    word[0] == 'o' || word[0] == 'u')
      cout<<"Words that start with vowels are not easily translated to Pig Latin"<<endl;
  else
  {
    cout<<"In Pig Latin: ";

    // get the size of the word:
    // x = strlen(word);

    // work backwards through the array and print each char:
    for(int i=strlen(word); i>=0; --i)
    {
      cout << word[i];
    }
    cout << "ay" << endl;

    // use the for loop shown above instead of this
    // while(word[x] != NULL)
    // {
    //   cout<<word[x];
    //   ++x++;
    // }
    // cout<<word[0]<<"ay"<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this code. I hadn't heard of #include<cstring> or strlen before!

Answer (score 0):

So first identify the mistakes in the given program :

1. You need an array of type char, in the given program the array is declared as type string and another variable which is not an array is declared as character. So what you need is :

   ```
   char word[20];
   ```
2. When taking input, you need to use the declared character array :

   ```
   cin>>word;
   ```
3. There's a difference between `=` and `==`, the latter is used for comparison while the former is used for assignment. So if you wanted to compare if `a` is the same as `b` then you would do `if(a==b)` but if you wanted to put the value of `b` into `a` you would do `a = b`. It's important to note `if(a = b)` will always be true if both `a` and `b` are valid variables. Therefore you would need to change the if statement to :

   ```
   if(word[0] == 'a' || word[0] == 'e' || word[0] == 'i' || word[0] == 'o' || word[0] == 'u')
   ```
4. Finally, to output the string backwards you just need to start printing from the last character in the array to the first. To get the last index of the array, use the strlen function to get the length of the character array which would be the same as the last index:

   ```
   n = strlen(word);
   ```

   Then just go backwards from there :

   ```
   while(n>=0)
   { cout<<word[n];
     n--;
   }
   ```

   which will give you your character array in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the code to me! This helped a lot! :D